# reuse results from sql functions

Tags: sql, oracle

Take a look at the beginning of this query:

```
SELECT
   sum(decode(REGEXP_COUNT(tpdd.domain, 'thedomain.com'), 1, tpdd.size, 0, 0))  SizeClient,
   sum(decode(REGEXP_COUNT(tpdd.domain, 'thedomain.com'), 1, 0, 0, tpdd.size))  SizeThirdParty,
   ...
```

Is there a way to reuse the results of the "REGEXP_COUNT(tpdd.domain, 'thedomain.com')" function?  I should hope that the oracle server is smart enough to do that but I can't guarantee it, and besides, the code would look better without the repeated code.

Comment: You could, presumably, move the calculation into the `tpdd` subquery (or transform the `tpdd` query into an inline view and add that).  I wouldn't expect any vaguely recent version of Oracle to recompute the function call, however.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a CTE like this:

```
 WITH domain_regex as
 (
    SELECT tpdd.domain, REGEXP_COUNT(tpdd.domain,'thedomain.com') as regex_res
    FROM ...
 ) 
 SELECT
    sum(decode(d.regex_res, 1, tpdd.size, 0, 0))  SizeClient,
    sum(decode(d.regex_res, 1, 0, 0, tpdd.size))  SizeThirdParty,
    ...
 JOIN domain_regex d on tpdd.domain = d.domain
```